# VS Code: How to change text color of selected text?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to change the selected text of highlighted text in VS Code. There are 3 ways I can select text.

My current editor settings are:

```
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#e8fc37",
        "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#e8fc37",
    },
```

(1) When I *first* click or select a string of text,then hiting `CMD+d`, I can select the next occurrences of a string of text:

[image]

(2) But if I try to select the text by first searching for it in the same file(CMD+f), then selecting the next occurrences (pressing CMD+d), the color doesn't highlight. The text does in fact highlight, but it's **very** difficult to tell. You can only really tell by looking in the gutter where the line numbers are.

[image]

(3) When I use the Search command (searching among all files; CMD+Shift+f), and I click on one of the search results, even though it clearly tells me what line the text is one, I can't easily tell where in the line the text is being highlighted. This is tricky when the line is longer or filled special characters.

[image]

In all these cases, I would like to have the selected text, whether I'm selecting it by using `CMD+d` or clicking on a result in a search side bar to have the text be dark gray in the foreground, and yellow in the background. I have been able to achieve the background color change, but don't know the editor key for any of the foreground texts.

How can I get selected text to be yellow in the background (which I have done) with dark gray text?

Comment: try adding a transparency to the css color `"editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#e8fc3780"` the same word the `wordHighlightBackground`. Find and then Cmd+D does change the color of the next find text but only slightly because of the transparency of the background colors. Maybe your find background color has a high opacity and the select-next has a low opacity. Changing the forground color seems to be a performance issue in VSC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found a decent solution. Check out 123Dev's [response](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/34105#issuecomment-507045409). I just copied the Border key and values and I'm happy enough with it.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    // Totally Transparent
    "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#ffffff00",
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#ffffff00",
    // Borders
    "editor.findMatchBorder": "#ffff00",
    "editor.findMatchHighlightBorder": "#ff0000",
    "editor.selectionHighlightBorder": "#ffffff",
    "editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#272727",
    // Selection
    "editor.selectionBackground": "#771835",
    "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#771835",
    // Misc
    "editorCursor.foreground": "#00ff00",
    "editor.lineHighlightBackground": "#181818",
    "editor.findMatchBackground": "#000000",
    // Debugger
    "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#410d18",
    "statusBar.debuggingForeground": "#dddddd"
}
```

Comment: It is 2022 and the issue by default it is still there, there is almost no difference between regular searchs and ctrl+d selections. I copy your configuration and I adjusted a bit. Now I finally could see the difference!. Thank you for sharing your configuration!